# Как в Excel провернуть такой фокус ?

Tags: vba, excel, макросы

Каким образом в Excel возможно реализовать такую хитрость: 
в созданной таблице, приведён перечень в виде нескольких гиперссылок на поиск в интернете ( браузер ОПЕРА если это важно ). Один клик = один переход в браузер. Как можно упростить задачу и скажем одним кликом запустить 10 гиперссылок одновременно, что бы они открылись в разных окнах ?
Спасибо !

Answer (score 2):

Функция перехода по ссылке (в адресе источник, откуда взято):

```
Dim TempHyperLink As Hyperlink
Set TempHyperLink = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
        "http://www.vr-online.ru/forum/vba-kak-v-ms-office-word-postavit-na-knopku-perehod-po-ssylke-3587")
TempHyperLink.Follow
TempHyperLink.Delete
```

Осталось сделать цикл в котором по очереди подставлять разные URL.
P.S. Еще можете поискать другие варианты запросом **excel vba переход по ссылке**

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо ! Заработало ! Я остановился на P.S.